# Getting write() system call to write in file

Tags: c, system-calls

I am having trouble getting write() system call to write in a file. So far, I manage to only print gibberish into a file that is said to be a binary file. I know that we must somehow preformat write().

How do I actually get write() to create/write in a text file?

```
void writeNumbers(int array[], int size, char* fname, int hexFlag) {

    int fp;
    int i;
    char buf[512];


    fp = open(fname, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND);         


    if (fp < 0) {
            close(fp);
            char msg[] = "Cannot write";
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg) - 1);
            exit(1);
    }


    if (hexFlag == 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
                    snprintf(buf, sizeof(int), "%d ", array[i]);
                    write(fp, buf, sizeof(buf));
            }
    } else {
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
                    snprintf(buf, sizeof(int), "%x ", array[i]);
                    write(fp, buf, sizeof(int));
            }
    }
    write(fp, "message", sizeof(buf));


    close(fp);
}
```

Here I am trying to print an array of ints either in hexadecimal or decimal formats.

Comment: these lines: if (fp < 0) {
            close(fp); are incorrect as cannot close a file that failed to open,  Therefore, remove the line 'close(fp)' from that code block.

Comment: this line: write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg) - 1); should be: write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));

Comment: this line: write(fp, buf, sizeof(buf)); should be: write(fp, buf, strlen(buf));

Comment: this line: snprintf(buf, sizeof(int), "%d ", array[i]); is making the assumption that none of the values in array will be (if positive) greater than 9999 and (if negative) greater than -999  that constraint is not backed up by the rest of the code.  Therefore, it would be undefined behaviour if any value in array[] exceeded those limits.

Comment: this line: snprintf(buf, sizeof(int), "%x ", array[i]); is limiting the length of the hex digits to 4 characters, however; an int (typically 4 bytes) would contain 8 hex characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)  returns the number of characters printed into the buffer passed. Also it takes the maximum number of characters to print to the buffer as second argument, that typically is the size of the buffer, but also could be few.

You want to write out exactly the number of characters, as returned by `snprintf()`.

```
        if (hexFlag == 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
                int result = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d ", array[i]);
                if (0 > result)
                {
                  write(STDERR_FILENO, "snprintf() failed.\n", strlen("snprintf() failed.\n"));
                }
                else
                {
                  write(fp, buf, result);
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        ...
```

As general advise: Carefully read a function's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `snprintf` should take `sizeof(buffer)` instead of `sizeof(int)`.  Each call to `write` should take `strlen(buf)` as its 3rd argument.